# Grails - Spring Security Account Creation

Tags: security, grails, plugins, authentication, spring-security

I am using the Spring Security Core plugin and can successfully log users in and out of my application. However, when the user successfully signs up, I don't understand how to set that user's security context on the signup postback so that they can be redirected to a secure page without having to log in again. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually came upon this link, which does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7112838/469106

Here are the contents of that link:

If you don't have the password, you can load the user via

```
def user = User.findByUsername(username)
```

and setting the authority array in the 3-parameter constructor. Create the auths via

```
GrantedAuthority[] auths = user.authorities.collect { new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it.authority) }
```

Then you can omit the call to authenticate() and use:

```
SecurityContextHolder.context.authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, 'unknown', auths)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other link you reference is 2 years old. Since then I've added a `reauthenticate` method to SpringSecurityService. See section "6.2 SpringSecurityService" in the docs: 
http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/

Comment: Thanks. I don't really get how it works, though. If I call `springSecurityService.reauthenticate userInstance.username` by itself, how does the `SecurityContext` know what authorities the username has? This is the first authentication call the user will have ever made since they are brand new.

Comment: Read the source :) It does basically what you're doing, except that it loads the user from the database.